# Problem with copying main application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

OK , the eXercice is about to get the path to the running application i have done this by  :

```
NSFileManager *FManager = [ NSFileManager defaultManager ] ;
NSString *CurrentPath = [ FManager currentDirectoryPath ] ;
NSDictionary *infoPList = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString *appName = [infoPList objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"];
NSString *mainpath = [ CurrentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:appName ] ;
NSString *mainFile = [ mainpath stringByAppendingString:@".app" ] ;
```

then I try to copy the main file to the home directory

```
NSString *homedir = NSHomeDirectory();
if ( [ Fmanager fileExistsAtPath:mainfile ] == YES ) 
    NSLog(@" File exist " ) ;
else {
    NSLog(@" not eXist " );
}

if ( [ Fmanager copyItemAtPath:mainfile toPath:homedir error:NULL ] == YES ) {
    NSLog(@" COPY SUCC " ) ;
}
else {
    NSLog(@" COPY FAIL") ;
}
```

here the copy procedure fails and it also tells me that the main file does not even eXists ...ou
Can anyone help me please 
Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

By main file, do you mean the main executable?  Look at NSBundle for paths to various components of the compiled application.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]; // path to your.app
[[NSBundle mainBundle] executablePath]; // path to your.app main executable
```

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a bad idea to rely on the value of the current directory unless you just set it.  Anyway, you're making it too hard; the path to the app would be `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]`.

Comment: Thnx , but what i dont understand here is that the [ [ NSBundle mainbundle] executablepath ] should return the path to the main executable which is not the case , it return to me :
/Users/mayname/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.0/Applications/9FAA4D2E-D826-42D9-B068-D0B715064C59/Testme.app/Testme
Can someone please explain to me this , and what shall i use Bundlepath or executablePath ?
Thanks

Comment: That's the path to the main executable.